# Why is `gathered` undefined?

Tags: undefined, gather

Using the `gathered` environment causes my ide (TexStudio) to report an error

```
Error: Undefined control sequence. \begin{gathered}
```

even though I'm using the package `mathtools` (I also tried it with `amsmath`). Also the PDF comes out exactly as desired. But my ide keeps moving the view to the location of the error which is rather annoying.

A minimal example is

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{gathered}
x
\end{gathered}
\]
\end{document}
```

The error disappears if I *replace* `mathtools` with `amsmath`. But there are commands in `mathtools` that I need. And *adding* `amsmath` doesn't work. Also `mathtools` is supposed to load `amsmath` transitively.

The log file reports

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\\MT_gathered_env ...vir }}\fi \alignedspace@left 
                                                  \if #1t\vtop \else \if #1b...
l.6 \begin{gathered}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Answer (score 7):

At some point you have updated `mathtools` without updating `amsmath`. So a full fix would be to update `amsmath` using your miktex or texlive package manager however

```
\makeatletter
\def\alignedspace@left{\null\,}
\makeatother
```

will give the old behaviour.

You have not shown it but your log file would have had a warning from LaTeX that your `amsmath` was too old as `mathtools` specifies a requirement

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}[2016/11/05]
```

and your `amsmath` must be older than 2016 or it would define this command.